# Git inside git: is this a solution?

Tags: git, git-annex

Consider the following directory structure:

```
~
|
---~/everything
       |
       ---.gitignore
       |
       ---.git/
       |
       ---code/
             |
             ---project1/
                    |
                    ---.git/
```

That is:

- I have a git repo: `~/everything`;
- Inside the `everything` folder, there is another folder: `~/everything/code`;
- This `code` folder is added to .gitignore for the `everything` repo, so no files inside it are checked out to that repository;
- Now inside `code/`, I have several other git repos, e.g., `project1`.

The goal is to have my, e.g., `home` or `everything` folder version-controlled on its own (e.g., with `git-annex` for large files), and at the same time keep my `code` folder (consisting of several projects each with their own separate git repo) inside the same directory (e.g., for a unified backup of everything, etc.).

Do you see any reason this might not work, or any scenario that would lead into conflicts, problems, or data loss?

Comment: Too short for a proper answer, but check this out: git supports [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). You can use them to make repos depend on other, independent repos.